# redis-server is being crashed once reached max_memory reached, expected it just allow read without write

Tags: redis

[redis]
redis-server is being crashed once reached max_memory reached.
as per documentation, I expected it just allow read without write however its being crashed.
any solution for it, increasing max_memory will help but we need to limit the memory usage and stop redis server being crashed. any help appreciated. thank you

I increased max_memory, so no problem before hitting this limit however once this limit touched redis-server crashed.